# Compute minimum merging of DAGs

Tags: graph-theory, graph-isomorphism

Sorry for the vague title. I'm hoping someone can identify this problem by name and point me in the right direction to solving it (I think ILP could be used to solve it).

Given a set of DAGs $\{G_1, G_2, ...\}$ where $G_i=(V,E,labels(V))$ and $labels: V \rightarrow \{A, B, C, D\}$ (each vertex has a label – A, B, C, or D), I want to compute a new graph $H=(V',E',labels(V'))$ s.t. $\{G_1, G_2, ...\}$ are subgraphs of $H$.

In other words, I want to merge each $G_i$ into a single graph, such that there exists a subgraph isomorphism between $H$ and each $G_i$.

Comment: this might be the graph reconstruction problem (or a specialisation of it) https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reconstruction_conjecture - it may be useful terminology that the set of subgraphs is a 'deck'

Comment: What do you want to minimize?

Comment: I want to the smallest (least edges and nodes) where there are still subgraph isomorphisms between the larger graph and each $G_i$.

Answer (score 0):

If they are DAGs, just sort them topologically. As you label the vertices with a (small) fixed set, you can sort so that labels appear in one particular order, and then the matching between graphs is more of less finding longest common subsequences of the labels Might even try different label orders and see which one comes out best.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "labels appear in a particular order." If I topologically sort and labels are a property of the graph, the labels will sequence in the order of the topological sort (though there could be more than one top sorts).

Comment: Also if I'm thinking of this correctly, this will give me the largest common subgraphs of the DAGs, which isn't necessarily what I want. The DAGs might share more structure than the common subsequence would imply.